# How to open .xlsx files in MS Excel from VS Code?

Tags: ms-office, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to open certain files like xlsx/docx in external apps (preferably system defaults) from VS Code Explorer instead of just opening another tab in VS Code?

I want to be able to open xlsx/docx etc. in MS Office Apps by double clicking from the explorer, if that's possible at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After installing the extension called [open](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sandcastle.vscode-open), you can open ms files by default app with right click. (But it does not work in WSL)

[image: with right click]

Answer (score 15):

[Check this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cweijan.vscode-office) - both `.docx` and `.xlsx` are working good and you can even edit them.

Example of `.docx`:

[image: For docx]

Example of `.xlsx`:

[image: For xlsx]

Comment: I want to be able to open it in excel rather than vs code itself. The answer provided by @Gantrol seems to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open .xlsx files within vs code then this tool does the job. It is much faster then loading Excel I find.

[Excel Viewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GrapeCity.gc-excelviewer)